# Melt list variables

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I melt a `tbl_df` containing a list variable? I am simply looking for the inverse of

```
library( dplyr )

tbl <- data.frame( x = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), y = 1:4 ) %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  do( y = .$y )

tbl
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

  x        y
1 A <int[2]>
2 B <int[2]>
```

I thought of something like

```
tbl %>%
  mutate( y = unlist(y) )

Error: incompatible size (2), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1

library( reshape2 )
melt( tbl, id.vars = "x" )

Error: Can't melt data.frames with non-atomic columns
```

**Edit** This is the `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices datasets  stats     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.2     ggplot2_1.0.0 stringr_0.6.2 reshape2_1.4  plyr_1.8.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1   colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.0       gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.0.1   MASS_7.3-33      munsell_0.4.2   
 [9] parallel_3.1.0   proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2      scales_0.2.4     tools_3.1.0
```

`dplyr`was loaded after `plyr`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I added the `sessionInfo`. It's also version 0.2.

Comment: You cant unlist `y` and put it back into `tbl` as it's double of it's current size (from 2 to 4), thus the only way I can think of would be something like `data.frame(x = rep(tbl$x, sapply(tbl$y, length)), y = unlist(tbl$y))`

Comment: How about `tbl %>% do(data.frame(x = .$x, y = .$y))`?

Comment: I tried out `do` based on groups, as well, which also works but doesn't look much nicer: `tbl %>% group_by(x) %>% do(data.frame(y = unlist(.$y)))`

Comment: @aosmith I haven't benchmarked this, so this is just speculation, but I am afraid that this `do(data.frame(...))` thing is much slower than doing a simple `mutate( trallala )`. Thats what I meant by *not very elegant*. But still many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I was looking for something yesterday and came across `unnest` in package **tidyr**.  This function seems like a possible option for this situation - `unnest(tbl, y)`.

Comment: @aosmith @hadley thanks for the suggestion. Which `tidyr`version are you using? I'm running 0.1 which is not aware of `unnest` and trying to install the latest github version gives an error: `Error in data.frame(binary = binvers, source = srcvers, row.names = bins,  :
duplicate row.names: knitr`

Comment: Good question - I'm using the development version of `tidyr`, 0.1.0.9000, with R 3.1.1 (Windows).

Comment: @aosmith sorry, turned out that `devtools` caused the problem. `unnest` works like a charm. Do you want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unnest` function from **tidyr** (v. 0.1.0.9000) is another option that works nicely.

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(tbl, y)

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  x y
1 A 1
2 A 2
3 B 3
4 B 4
```

You can add it directly to your code chain, too

```
data.frame( x = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), y = 1:4 ) %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  do( y = .$y ) %>%
  unnest(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best option that I can think of is to use `data.table` for your "melting", like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tbl)[, list(y = unlist(y)), by = x][]
#    x y
# 1: A 1
# 2: A 2
# 3: B 3
# 4: B 4
```

Comment: The more I work with `dplyr` the more I am happy that it is compatible with `data.table` so I can choose the best from both worlds. I waited a bit for a pure `dplyr`solution but even the one @aosmith suggested in his comments does not look very elegant.